# Static library can't find CoreML model

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, coreml

I am going absolutely insane after 16-20 hours of debugging this.

I am building a static library (for React Native, if that matters) that makes use of a core ml model, let's call it FakeModel.mlmodel.

I have included the .mlmodel in "Compile Sources" and in source_files in my podspec. I have compiled the .mlmodel to get an .mlmodelc file that I have included in "Copy Bundle Resources" in the library's target build phase.

I can open the swift file from the main project, and see everything compile without errors. Building the main app also works, but once installed it gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Because of this:

```
    class var urlOfModelInThisBundle : URL {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
        return bundle.url(forResource: "FakeModel", withExtension:"mlmodelc")!
    }
```

The code above is in a file that was automatically generated by Xcode, and it has a comment at the top saying "This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.", so I am assuming editing the file is a bad idea.

What do I have to do fix this?

Comment: Instead of url try “FakeModel(configuration:)”

Comment: I cant change the code in urlOfModelInThisBundle, it's auto-generated when I import the model to xcode :(

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, have you found a fix?